# Angular import issue when using sub apps with the main app (usual setup with added projects folder)

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, subapplication

I have a big Angular 10 project. I used it as a one-application setup project. But since I wanted to move out different parts to run independently, I added sub-applications, which created the projects folder and the applications under it, and modified the main angular.json and some other files, nothing new. When I run the sub-applications, nothing bad happens, no errors, and all is fine. But when I try to run the main application, I start getting errors like `NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'section'.` This points me to an import error, but the CommonModule which could cause this error is imported in the main app and also in the sub-apps. Is there any configuration I should add to prevent these errors from happening? I am new to the multi-application workspace setup method in Angular.

Comment: Can you provide me with a repo example in order to solve it there? thanks!

Comment: It is really huge, frankly... I uploaded a screenshot of how the main and the sub-applications look next to each other, and I share whatever files were needed but I can't make a demo repo from that giant monster :/ - https://yourimageshare.com/ib/0qscrzV8rn
So the sub-app is the one inside projects/customer-menu, the main is the outer src/app/

Comment: ouf.. you run an entire new app just to run a menu? If I were you I would try to component it

Comment: It is not a menu it is just the naming :) It has a lot of its own logic, services, and so on... In the main app I take one route to use this component and then everything is handled in the sub-app. Or it should be if I weren't getting those strange errors..